# Is there anyway to see all the functions provided by a contract that has been deployed on Near protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to use make function calls against a deployed contract on Near.  Documentation is non-existent as is so often the case.

Is there anyway to see all the functions provided by a contract that has been deployed on Near protocol?  The contract is on zhiwong5.testnet

Answer (score 1):

Yes , [stats gallery](https://stats.gallery/) enables you to see all the methods within a deployed contract on near protocol and you can even execute the functions from there.

Here is the link of methods for your contract : https://stats.gallery/testnet/zhiwong5.testnet/contract?t=week